# Where is MVC 5 template in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I searched for it in the internet, but the problem is that I do not have general MVC template only this one on the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special template called MVC 5 in VS 2013. However, you need to select .Net Framework 4.5.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why choose NET Framework 4.5.1 instead 4.5?

Comment: If you want to use [new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of .Net Framework 4.5.1, you will need it. Otherwise, 4.5 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 installs .NET 4.5 automatically. So it shouldn't be that issue. I think you need to change the framework version from ".NET Framework 4" to ".NET Framework 4.5".

[image]

Then after that you can select ASP.NET Web Application and pick which ASP.NET project type you want. MVC, webforms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .NET Framework 4.5 (or higher) to get the "ASP.NET Web Application" which let's you select from Web Forms, MVC, Web API, etc.